# Formula help for mileage calculation/constant

Tags: google-sheets

I need to create a spreadsheet in Google Drive that will let me calculate mileage for my employees.  I know the exact mileage to the locations they'd have to drive to.  What I need to do is have a constant entered when they type in the location code.  Ex... If in C1 they enter the code 2 then in D1 it will automatically input the mileage (1.8). I'll only have 2 mileage codes.  How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps this answer is of use: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/16757/29140

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a drop-down list of your locations, see the instructions on data validation at https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103 . Presumably you'd use it with a formula to convert location names to numeric values.

If you want to create a custom function to do that conversion, see the quick-start tutorial at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros . It gives an example JavaScript function that converts meters to miles, also a longer example that calls the Google Maps API to look up the driving distance between two addresses.

Answer (score 0):

> If in C1 they enter the code 2 then in D1 it will automatically input the mileage (1.8).

I have a different interpretation of the requirement, for which [SWITCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690) would be very adequate (in D1):

```
=switch(C1,2,1.8,6,5.6)
```

With the above entry of `2` in C1 will return `1.8` in D1, and `6` return `5.6`. Text, `0` or blank will return `#N/A`.

For a lot of mileage codes alternatives such as a lookup table may be more practical, but the above should suit where there are only a few codes.